# Entity Framework EF returns null list in some occasions (eager loading)

Tags: c#, list, caching, null, entity-framework-6

EF sometimes returns a null list instead of an empty list. This doesn't always happen but might have to do with EF's caching system.

I'm eager loading related entities in a one to many relationship. Trying to get POFreezes list loaded.

Ran into a problem where when **two RMALines with the same POFreeze**.

- The 1st RMALine's relationships are populated just fine.
- The 2nd RMALine's relationships (POFreeze list) are returned as null.

Checked database and the record exists.

I ran SQL Profiler and ran the query that EF is producing and the records being returned are correct. The POFreeze is being returned.

```
            return await _context.RMALines
                        .Where(c => c.Approved == 0)
                        .Include(c => c.CPSOLine.SOLine.POFreezes)
                        .OrderBy(c => c.RMAKey)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Any idea of why i'm getting a null List returned instead of an empty one?

Comment: @Dennis1679 Doesn't work like that in EF6. `Thenclude` is EF-core.

Comment: Is there anything happening in the constructors of the involved classes? I think it's better anyway if you show some more detail (classes, mapping).

Comment: Have you tried .Include(c => c.CPSOLine).ThenInclude(c=> c.SOLine) .ThenInclude(c=> c.POFreezes).OrderBy(c => c.RMAKey)  ?